# How do you make ajax work from different directories?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

First, let me show you the folder structure:

```
public_html[]  
     |_ project_folder[]  
            |_another_folder[]  

            |_xml_folder[]  
                   |_xmlfile.xml   

            |_ js_folder[]  
                   |_javascriptfile.js  

            |_ file.html  
            |_ file2.html
```

I have some file.html and file2.html load use jQuery ajax on document load. Ajax uses this code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "xml/xmlfile.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
            ...
            ...
            ...
}
```

These works fine when the HTML files are found on the root directory of the files (just the way they are now)

Now, when I move an html file to a folder (say, moving file2.html to another_folder), loading the xml file doesn't work anymore. Take not that I've changed the necessary src tags on the html ie: from src\"js/javascriptfile.js" to src=\"../js/javascriptfile.js".

What I haven't changed is the "url" on the javascript file. And now, the XML isn't loading because it's trying to look for the XML file on it's own directory (another_folder/xml/xmlfile.xml), and not from the root directory where it's located.

My question is, what should be done in order to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Use an absolute URL in the js file e.g.

```
'/project/xml/xmlfile.xml'
```

If you want it to be more general than that, there are other things you could do, like reading the current url and building the ajax url from that.

**Update:** responding to comment
An example of how you might generate the proper path.
If projects are always the first subdirectory, this should work to build the proper url.

```
function xml_url(){
var first_dir_regexp = /https?:\/\/[^\/]+\/([^\/]+)\/.+/;
matches = first_dir_regexp.exec(document.location.toString());
return matches[1]+"/xml/xmlfile.xml";
}
//...
xml_url()
```

This code uses a regexp to pull out the first directory of a url and appends /xml/xmlfile.xml to it.

**e.g.**  if the page is example.com/project1/awesome/index.html, it returns example.com/project1/xml/xmlfile.xml

**Note** this code is pretty fragile, you would probably want to add some checks to it. It's just an example.

If your projects are more than one level deep, you should consider adding some config settings that let the javascript know more about the environment it is running in.

Comment: I've tried your answer, and the problem is that I wanted the HTML files to "not care" where they are put, so that they can be placed in the directory however low they are from the document root (and sometimes, it will be about 3-4 folders low).

As for getting the current url, I've also tried it, but how do you get the home directory of the file so there would be something to compare the current url to?

eg:
The current file is in "public_html/project_folder/another_folder/another_sub_folder/file2.html"

How do you get "project_folder from all of that?" What if the file was located 1dir lower?

Answer (score 4):

Use urls that are relative to the web root, not the current directory.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/xml/xmlfile.xml", // note the leading slash
        dataType: "xml",
            ...
            ...
            ...
}
```

Comment: Same as my comment for the guy above:

"I wanted the HTML files to "not care" where they are put, so that they can be placed in the directory however low they are from the document root (and sometimes, it will be about 3-4 folders low). As for getting the current url, I've also tried it, but how do you get the home directory of the file so there would be something to compare the current url to? eg: The current file is in "public_html/project_folder/another_folder/another_sub_folder/file2.html" How do you get "project_folder from all of that?" What if the file was located 1dir lower?"

Comment: If you reference the XML file from the web root, it shouldn't matter where the HTML files are located.  The XML file will always be referenced where it is as long as you don't move it's folder in the hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for // note the leading slash

Answer (score 1):

As I hate duplication of code, I've had the same problem too.

I figured it out this way:

My directory structure:

```
include_db/
  dbconnect.php
main_project/
  shared_code/
    ajax/
      ajax_script.php
    shared_js.php
  sub_project/
    sub_index.php
  index.php
```

Please note, that I really have javascript in **.php** file! I'll explain why lower.

From **index.php** I include shared java declaring this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./shared_code/shared_js.php"></script>
```

From **sub_index.php** I do it this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../shared_code/shared_js.php?path=."></script>
```

The **shared_js.php** file is using AJAX, so here is why is it in **.php** instead of **.js**:

```
$.ajax({
  url: ".<?php echo $_GET[path]; ?>/shared_code/ajax/ajax_script.php",
  ...
```

Because I have to alter the path to that ajax script based on where do I call it from. And that is the content of **$_GET[path]** variable which I set in **index.php** or **sub_index.php**.

The AJAX script **ajax_script.php** is then using paths relative to itself again so it will have something like you would normally do:

```
<?php
    require("../../../include_db/dbconnect.php");
```